# Can't get the flutter posted image to the nodejs server

Tags: node.js, flutter, file-upload

I want to get the image that have been posted to the nodejs flutter. I am using the below code in the flutter:

```
  _openCameraPicture(BuildContext context) async {
    var image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() async {
      selectedImage = File(image!.path);
      if (Network.isConnected) {
        var request = http.MultipartRequest(
            'POST', Uri.parse("${Network.serverUrl}/upload_image"));
        request.fields['title'] = "testImage";
        request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
            'picture', selectedImage!.readAsBytesSync(),
            filename: selectedImage!.path.split("/").last));
        var response =
            await request.send().then((value) => {Navigator.pop(context)});
        // if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        //   Do something ...
        // }
      }
    });
  }
```

In my nodejs server api I use:

```
router.post("/upload_image", PhoneInfoCtrl.apiUploadImage);
```

But I can not get the image and upload it to the server. My apiUploadImage is like:

```
static async apiUploadImage(req, res, next) {
    try {
         console.log(req);

         res.sendStatus(200);
       
    } catch (error) {
        //res.status(500);
    }
}
```

How may I extract the image from req? I tested some ways but was not possible. Is something wrong with my flutter code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using multer in my router in nodejs.

```
const path = require('path');
const multer  = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination : (req, file, cb) =>{
        cb(null , "./public/images")
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) =>{
        console.log(file);
        cb(null , Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    },
});
```

then:

```
router.post("/upload_image", upload.single("picture"),myController.apiUploadImage);
```